# img tag in svelte not showing image paths in src attribute

Tags: image, svelte, intellisense, sveltekit, src

when I start inputting into the src of an image in svelte, I don't get the path/intellisense path

```
<img src="../" alt="brands" />
```

I expected that I should gwt access to my folders and navigate to where the image is

from the intellisense, all I see is:

[snippet of the result I see in my IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIsut.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a path like this anyway. Import the asset in the script, that way it is included in the build with a hash, making sure one does not run into caching issues.

```html
<script>
  import brandsSrc from '../brands.jpg';
</script>
<img src={brandsSrc} alt="brands" />
```

Comment: Hmmm.. thank you. However, even when I tried doing this, the paths weren't still showing.
Would you recommend the same when working on image sources that are in a JSON file?

Also, I started putting my images in the static folder and they seem to work fine, what do you think?

Comment: If regular import paths are not completed there is something wrong with your IDE/config/extensions. Would not recommend putting images in `static`, this could lead to users seeing outdated images if an image is updated, depends on specific server being used and what headers it sends, though. If the paths are defined in a JSON file, they will not be processed, so you probably will have to use `static`, would recommend adding some cache busting strategy manually then, e.g. by adding a query string with a version.